# How to implement Facebook and Twitter notifications table in iPhone app

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using Parse to deliver push notifications to my iPhone app. However, when I send notifications, they are getting cut off because they are too long. How can I make a notifications table so that when a user taps the notification, they are taken to a notifications table in the app that displays all notifications in their entirety?

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, if the notification is too long to be displayed properly, it probably shouldn't be a notification in the first place. Hypothetically, you can pass the entire text of the notification you would like to display as a key-value pair in the notification payload and then use that to create a object in your app. You would have to create, add and cache the desired text in the payload and add it to your TableViewController's data source. You can use deep-linking from there to route to your custom notification table. In practice this is pretty round-about and not particularly reliable since notifications come in on a "best-try-but-no-promises" basis. If you're already using parse, you should probably consider creating objects there you can fetch with your desired info. Cloud code can handle object creation pretty easily for example.